# Unix script to compress any format of files

Tags: unix, shell

Im a new to Unix shell scripting .I have to write a Unix script

A) To  find a files in a particular directory which has got csv as well .txt
B) Compress those files both csv and txt 
c)currently under that have not been modified in 1095 days
d)Send a mail to the receipent

Kindly help me

Comment: could you please tell whether it is homework so that we can adapt the answers?

Answer (score 2):

The commands you need to look at are:

- `find` which can be used to find files (including those of a certain age (such as with the `-mtime` option) and name (such as `-name '*.csv'`).
- either `compress` or `gzip` for compressing.
- either `mail` or `mailx` for sending mail.

Those aren't necessarily an exhaustive list of the potential programs for doing those tasks but they should be available on the vast majority of UNIX-like boxes.

If you need help with those specific commands, your best bet is to first look into executing (for example):

```
man gzip
```

to see how they work.

Comment: kindly send a small unix script for reference To find a files in a particular directory which has got csv as well .txt B) Compress those files both csv and txt c)currently under that have not been modified in 1095 days d)Send a mail to the receipent

Comment: Sorry, @Harry, while I'm happy to provide general pointers and help for questions, I generally get paid for bespoke work :-) You will learn a great deal more if you attempt to do it yourself with the information I provided.

Comment: @Harry SO is not a code writing service that does your homework (or worse, work that you get paid to do)